# backbone.js: keeping an element after removal from a collection

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, models

I'm trying to move a model between two collections based on drag and drop events in the UI (from one "box" to another). Now when I remove the element from its original collection, it apparently ceases to exist because it doesn't show up in the new collection either (if I comment out removal, the appearence in the other collection works).

I have the intuition that this is because of the idea that each model corresponds to a server side collection and removing something from a collection normally even goes back to the server to kill it. Here, however, I want my models to be a bit more free-floating. Is that possible? Am I using Backbone wrongly?

Update

Ok so this is an excerpt of my code. If necessary I can create a fiddle but maybe this helps to highlight what's happening:

```
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var item = ui.draggable.data("model");
        newcollection.add(item);
        console.log(item);
        oldcollection.remove(item);
        console.log(item);
    }
```

now, console output looks like this:

```
d {attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid: "c83", changed: Object, _silent: Object…}

d {_previousAttributes: Object, _pending: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, changed: Object, _silent: Object…}
```

So apparently the model itself has changed while nothing else than its removal from the collection has happened. I see now it hasn't actually "ceased to exist" but still - ?

Comment: Do you have any event handlers bound to the `remove` event of `oldcollection` or `item`? Use the debugger to trace into `remove` event on the model that removing it from the collection triggers and see if anything there calls `set` which would explain why `_previousAttributes` is showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out I need to change the order of add and remove; otherwise the removal of the UI corresponding element is triggered both for the old and the new one... thanks for the comments though, helped nudge me into the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Removing a model from a collection does not delete that model from the server. That's what `model.destroy()` does. [Here's the source of `Collection.remove`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-86). When in doubt about backbone, go straight to the source. It's small and very easy to read and comprehend.

You probably have a bug elsewhere in your code, but we'll need a code sample or jsfiddle to help you find it.

Comment: fair enough, I did actually marvel at the annotated source some time back. after looking there again, I still don't understand what's going on - see above.